# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" infura on contract deploy

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to deploy contract i am using web3.js version web3@0.20.4 with infura node

following code i am trying

```
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/metamask"));
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

let privateKey = new Buffer('8A0F4E01AC43A014F9F13CF68E', 'hex');

let source = fs.readFileSync('contract.sol', 'utf8');// solc file source decided by yourself
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts[':Adeel'].interface;
let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts[':Adeel'].bytecode;

// Contract object
const MyContract = new web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));

// Get contract data
const contractData = MyContract.new.getData({
    data: '0x' + bytecode
});

const gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
const gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(gasPrice);
const gasLimitHex = web3.toHex(300000);

const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.coinbase);
const nonceHex = web3.toHex(nonce);

const rawTx = {
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
    data: contractData,
    from: '0x5488365e6785e571762ee980400e64c62853c2c0'
};

const tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);
const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), (err, hash) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

    // Log the tx, you can explore status manually with eth.getTransaction()
    console.log('contract creation tx: ' + hash);

    // Wait for the transaction to be mined
    waitForTransactionReceipt(hash);
});

function waitForTransactionReceipt(hash) {
    console.log('waiting for contract to be mined');
    const receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
    // If no receipt, try again in 1s
    if (receipt == null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            waitForTransactionReceipt(hash);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        // The transaction was mined, we can retrieve the contract address
        console.log('contract address: ' + receipt.contractAddress);
        //testContract(receipt.contractAddress);
    }
}
```

error is here

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/var/opt/webserver/adeel/adeelotxeth/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/var/opt/webserver/adeel/adeelotxeth/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:101:18)
    at RequestManager.send (/var/opt/webserver/adeel/adeelotxeth/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32)
    at Eth.get [as coinbase] (/var/opt/webserver/adeel/adeelotxeth/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:107:62)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/opt/webserver/adeel/adeelotxeth/test.js:26:53)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: Did you register with infura.io so they assign your own token to be able to connect?

Answer (score 1):

**Never show your private key to anyone!
Your 0.023752305 Ether can be stolen.**

About question: check connection to https://ropsten.infura.io/metamask
Now this page has code 404